# Textures and model keeps messing up when exporting

Tags: modeling, texturing, export

I have made a model of a katana for Roblox. But when I export it messes up my textures and model.
The blade sides disapear, so there is only a thin line in the middle
The bottom of the handle loses a part
Everything loses its color

1st picture is how it looks in Roblox Studio
2nd picture is what it is supposed to look like
3rd picture is the full model
[image: Katana Model For Roblox]

Comment: maybe make sure that the normals are correctly flipped: in Edit mode select all and Shift N

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures